How to make livewire side to know about alpinejs-multiselect selection?
In laravel 10/ livewire 3/ tailwindcss 3 app I to make multiselect based on
https://github.com/alexpechkarev/alpinejs-multiselect code and I made it working properly, but how to make livewire side to know current selected options ?
I define on livewire side :
class ReactionsChartStatistics extends Component
{
    use AppCommonTrait;

    // selected users in filter
    #[Session]
    public array $filterUsers = [];

    // list of users to show in multiselect
    public array $usersSelectionItems;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->usersSelectionItems = User::get()->pluck('name','id')->toArray();
        ...
    }
    public function render()
    {
        ...
        return view('livewire.admin.reactions-chart-statistics')->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }

and in resources/views/livewire/admin/reactions-chart-statistics.blade.php template :
   $filterUsers::{{ print_r($filterUsers, true) }}<br>;
   <div class="w-full"  x-data="alpineMultiSelect({selected:['', '1'], elementId:'usersMultiSelection'})">
        <select class="hidden " tabindex="10" id="usersMultiSelection" wire:model="filterUsers">
        @foreach($usersSelectionItems as $key=>$label)
            <option value="{{$key}}" data-search="{{$label}}">{{$key}}=>{{$label}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

method alpineMultiSelect is defined in resources/js/app.js file.
But when I select users in multiselect component array $filterUsers is not updated as I need.
Looks like  multiselect component is not shown as it is...
How can I do it ?
UPDATED BLOCK :
looking at example with at
sth : $wire.entangle

I made next :
In component I have $filterUsers declared:
class ReactionsChartStatistics extends Component
{
    // selected users in filter
    #[Session]
    public array $filterUsers = [];

and in blade file this var used :
<div class="w-full"
     x-data="alpineMultiSelect({selected:['', '1'], elementId:'usersMultiSelection', selectedValues : $wire.entangle('filterUsers')})">

    <select class="hidden " tabindex="10" id="usersMultiSelection">
        @foreach($usersSelectionItems as $key=>$label)
            <option value="{{$key}}" data-search="{{$label}}">{{$key}}=>{{$label}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    ... 

where selectedValues var is also used in app.js :
...
// get selected values
    selectedValues() {
        return this.options.filter(op => op.selected === true).map(el => el.value)
   }
...

It does not work anyway. Also looking at the code seems  select box is hidden by default with
style="display:none;" 
                            

attribute. Can it be key of the problem ?

You can use x-data="{ Sth : $wire.entangle('Your Livewire Variable')}"
Read more at Sharing state using $wire.entangle

Please read UPDATED BLOCK
